# Display contact information for each car owner

Tags: nodes, emails

I am trying to view contact information for each user who will be the car owner in this case. so in each car in car content type I want to display user info with each car he post

best

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: how could I view owner (user) contact information for each car (content type)?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. redhatlab's answer about covers it - use a View as he described.

Answer (score 2):

How do you gather the contact information? Is it profile fields or a node connected to the user account?

Regardless of the method you can create a view that will use the author of the node as the argument of the view (D6) or contextual filter (D7) to bring the contact information for the user. One thing to consider is that you might have to create a relationship to the entity or method you used to collect the information.

After the view is created the next thing will be to decide how to present it, maybe you want to create a block, or attach it at the end of the car content type or make it a tab, all those options are available in views as well.

Comment: thanks redhatlab, I have content type car and a car owner who can add car for sell for what I am suppose to make a view for the car of the user? sorry for this

Comment: You're welcome. Were you able to do it with a view?